# casting pcap_if_t* to pcap_if_t** in c++

Tags: c++, libpcap

I have working of `pcap` library to `sniff` network traffic in c++. 
In `pcap` library the `pcap_if_t` is a `struct` as below :

```
struct pcap_if {
    struct pcap_if *next;
    char *name;     /* name to hand to "pcap_open_live()" */
    char *description;  /* textual description of interface, or NULL */
    struct pcap_addr *addresses;
    bpf_u_int32 flags;  /* PCAP_IF_ interface flags */
};
typedef struct pcap_if pcap_if_t;
```

now, i am confused about using of `&alldevs` value in `int pcap_findalldevs(pcap_if_t **, char *);` prototype as the first value in bellow code. while, `pcap_if_t *alldevs` is a pointer and is not match with `pcap_if_t **` parameter (which is a pointer that refers to another pointers).

```
pcap_if_t *alldevs;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

/* Retrieve the device list from the local machine */
if (pcap_findalldevs(&alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in pcap_findalldevs_ex: %s\n", errbuf);
    exit(1);
}
```

For example even, i test "pointer to pointer" (a chain of pointers) with `int **arr` statement. i defined `int **arr` as a `matrix` :

```
int **arr = new int*[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new int[3];
}
```

Then defined `void print_arr(int **arr, int r, int c)` function, due to print `matrix` values and gave it two different parameters (`arr` and `&arr2`):

```
int *arr2 = static_cast<int*>(*arr);

print_arr(arr, 5, 3);              // arr defined in top
print_arr(&arr2, 5, 4);            // arr2 is a pointer as *arr2
```

Regardless of offered example, `c++` how behave with this conversion? its a few ambiguous to realize.

Comment: `&` gets the *address of* something (a pointer to it)... this should be covered in any beginner-level C++ book or tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` operator in this context is the `address of` operator. When you take the address of a variable, you get a pointer to that variable. A pointer stores an address.

e.g.:

```
int a = 1;
int *b = &a;
```

`b` now points to your `a` variable. Since `a` has the type `int`, `&a` gives you a type of pointer to int, an `int*`

The same thing happens if you do it one more time:

```
int a = 1;
int *b = &a;
int **c = &b;
```

Now `c` points to `b`. Since `b` has the type `int *`, `&b` gives you the type pointer to an int pointer, an `int **`

The same thing happens in your function call

```
 if (pcap_findalldevs(&alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
```

You take the address of the `alldevs` variable. Since `alldevs` has the type `pcap_if_t*` , `&alldevs` has the type `pcap_if_t**`.

You could do it like this too:

```
  pcap_if_t *alldevs;
  pcap_if_t **alldevs_ptr = &alldevs;

 if (pcap_findalldevs(alldevs_ptr, errbuf) == -1)
```

Comment: i know all of these, and ‍i know `&` to get address of a variable, but i confused about `int **c = &b;`. because i thought `&` is just for `variables` like `int a = 1;
int *b = &a;` and not for `pointers`. but what if use of `int **c = b;` instead of `int **c = &b;`?

Comment: i know `&` is for getting the address of `variable` in left side. but what is the meaning of `&` in left side of a `pointer`?

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi As I have shown in the answer here, there is no difference when & is at the left side of a pointer. A pointer can be a  variable. A variable can be a pointer. You take the address of a variable that is a pointer, and you get a pointer to that pointer - which people call a pointer to a pointer or a double pointer. If you use `int **c = b;` then the type of `b` is an `int*` while the type of `c` is an `int **`, even if that compiles you are not allowed to assign an `int*` to an `int**`, their types are not compatible.

Comment: I got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna offer a good example with this code :

```
int f = 48;
int *g = &f;
int **h = &g;
int ***i = &h;
int ****j = &i;

cout << j << endl;
cout << &i << endl;
```

Here, `j` is a chain pointer that contains `i` address, so output will be as bellow :

```
0x7ffe373a6220
0x7ffe373a6220
```

Two results shown either `j` value (which address `pointed` to) and `i` memory address, which two are the same because `j` contains `&i`. and also `h` and `&g` as :

```
cout << h << endl;
cout << &g << endl;
```

Also, output shown `h` value (that pointed to `g` address) and `&g`, which here are the same :

```
0x7ffe373a6210
0x7ffe373a6210
```